# Is there a method find_child_or_create similar to find_or_create in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wonder if there is a method that returns all child objects of an object, or create a new child object if none of them exists.

Such a method is convenient for creating nested form, where it often the case that because a child object has not been initialized that the nested form does not show up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in nested forms:

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for @parent.children || @parent.children.build do |child| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

or wrap it as a model method:

```
class Model < AR::Base
  ...
  def children_form
    children || children.build
  end
end
```

then use it in form

```
<%= f.fields_for @parent.children_form do |child| %>
```

Comment: That logic belongs in the controller or model, not the view.

Comment: Yeap, It belongs to model or presenter, not controller :)

Comment: Thanks floor. I think in case of nested form, Rails should have instantiate a child object when none is available as default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method as far as I know.